# How to apply def function in full dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, user-defined-functions

I need help to correct the function. I am confused for two things.

1. how to put for loop into def function.
2. Please, Correct my other function. It works only on single column

```
raw_data = {'age1': [23,45,21],'age2': [10,20,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2'])
df
```

It works well.

```
l = list(df.columns)
for c in l:
  df[c]=np.where(df[c]>45,df[c]+100,df[c])
```

1. It does not work properly and add more value than 100. What is wrong here.

```
def fun(x):
  l = list(df.columns)
  for c in l:
    df[c]=np.where(df[c]>45,df[c]+100,df[c])
  return x
df.apply(fun)
```

2. Why i can't apply this function on full dataframe. Please correct...

```
def f(x):
  val=[]
  if x>=40:
      val = x+100
  else:
      val = x
  return val
df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions do different things.

The first option works because you're iterating over each column and applying np.where to each column once.

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = np.where(df[c] > 45, df[c] + 100, df[c])
```

`df`:

```
   age1  age2
0    23    10
1    45    20
2    21   150
```

---

In this case:

```
def fun(x):
  l = list(df.columns)
  for c in l:
    df[c]=np.where(df[c]>45,df[c]+100,df[c])
  return x
df.apply(fun)
```

The function `fun` is called for every column (via `apply`), but you're doing the complete operation each time.

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
for _ in df.columns:
    for c in df.columns:
        df[c] = np.where(df[c] > 45, df[c] + 100, df[c])
```

Notice the nested looping.

Hence why it produces `df`:

```
   age1  age2
0    23    10
1    45    20
2    21   250
```

---

The last option is close:

```
def f(x):
  val=[]
  if x>=40:
      val = x+100
  else:
      val = x
  return val

df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

However x is a Series of values (DataFrame column) which means that `x >= 40` does not work leading to an Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

And can be modified just slightly to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which applies the function to every cell in the DataFrame:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 45:  # Changed the bound to match the np.where condition
        val = x + 100
    else:
        val = x
    return val

df = df.applymap(f)
```

`df`:

```
   age1  age2
0    23    10
1    45    20
2    21   150
```

---

However, the more pandas approach here would be to use something like [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df > 45, df + 100)
```

`df`:

```
   age1  age2
0    23    10
1    45    20
2    21   150
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed answer. Really appreciate it. It solved lots of my questions and also gave me new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Filling and replacing na col values based on col type

```
df.transform(lambda x: x.fillna('') if x.dtype == 'float64' else x.float64(0))

df.transform(lambda x: x.replace('orange','juice') if x.dtype == 'object' else x.fillna(0))
```